# Excel 2013 formula for Missing Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet with over 5,000 records.

Spreadsheet contains new system users who need to be set up with two customer levels "account planning" and "financial control" for each of their assigned customers.

What formula do I use to find the missing customer levels?

Vlookup or Match Index?

- Col A = Customer Name
- Col B = Customer Level: "account planning" or "financial control"
- Col C = Employee Number (the sheet is sorted by this column)
- Col D = Login Name
- Col E = Last Name
- Col F = First Name

Comment: This question can't be answered using the information you have given.  How would **YOU** know which Customer Level is to be assigned?  Are there two Customer Names for each Employee Number?  Is the first Customer automatically the Account Planning type?  Please **EDIT** your question and **CLEARLY** describe what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far.

Comment: See this [ask] page for advice on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @Bandersnatch: Great comment!  I would guess that there are *meant to be* two rows for every Customer/Employee pair (and the user is trying to find unmatched pairs), but you’re right: the question is unanswerable as is.  Now, regarding your edit: we prefer that when you edit a post — and especially when a <2K user *suggests* an edit — you make all appropriate edits, and not just one.  (See what I did.)  At the very least, you should have noticed that the OP had each column listed on a separate line, and that that was rendered unreadable.  And delete signatures and taglines like “Thanks”.

Comment: Suggestion:  Convert this to an access database.  Writing queries and reports will make your job easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not perfectly clear; I am taking a guess: You want to verify if each customer has two lines, one with column B = "account planning" and one with B = "financial control":

Depending if you want a permanent solution, or a one-time, there are many ways. You also have the choice to use VBA code, or use simple formulas with a bit of tricking. Here is *one* possible solution that takes 30 seconds to do:

- Add a helper column G (or any other free column) that contains the columns A & B concatenated, like `=A2&B2`
- Add a helper column H that contains a VLOOKUP onto G, for the missing partner value A & the other possible B value, like `=VLOOKUP(A2&IF(B2="account planning","financial control","account planning"),$G$2:$G$5000,1,FALSE)`
- filter (or check) for where the latter helper column contains an error, you have the lines that are missing the other level.